Old black & white. Title is the main character's nickname
I think the movie is black and white. Was made in the 40's or up to the 60's maybe.
The main character is a man, and he goes by a shortened version of his actual last name. 
Like Pennywise, or something. 
A young boy comes to live with him, I think it's his nephew. 
I've searched for a few years online and cannot figure it out. 
Please help me identify this movie.  I would like to see it again.

I think it's Pimpernel Svensson. The main character name is Anders 'Pimpernel' Svensson.
From the summary of IMDB

In post-war Sweden, dairy-farmer Anders Svensson spends his time
  strumming his guitar and neglecting his chores. When he hears that his
  nephew, Ville Lundgren, is being detained [...] Anders
  gives him the bottles to carry on the ship and, because of the
  general's presence, the guards pass him through. Anders and the
  maybe/maybe-not deceived Badajsky part as friends, and Anders and his
  nephew head back to Sweden for a family reunion.

